# How do I route a URL using a query string in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I am re-writing an old project using Symfony2 so I can try out the framework. I have urls that will be of the form:

```
/profile/{id}
```

in the snazzy way that Symfony2 does it. However, the same page was originally found by doing:

```
/profile.php?id=12345
```

So, in case someone has an old URL, I'd like to redirect these links. The problem is, I don't know how to catch routes of this nature. I tried

```
/profile.php?id={id}
```

but that didn't seem to work. How can I set up this route?

**Follow-up:** I do not want to do "catch-all" (because it is non-intuitive to me so I fear future bugs), and I would prefer not to do it via htaccess for the same reason. I think the best option is to match "/profile.php" then in the controller, check that "id" exists in query-string and redirect accordingly. If it does not, I will redirect to 404.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two options here:

1. You map your old schema (/profile.php?id=54321) onto the new (/profile/54321) using mod_rewrite (in case you use Apache).
2. You write a mapper within Symfony. That means at the end of your list of routes you specify a pattern that will just catch everything not yet catched:

---

```
whatever:
  pattern: /{whatever}
  defaults: { _controller: CoreBundle:Default:whatever }
  requirements:
    whatever: .+
```

---

For (2) you will have to check what the Request-object offers you for the queries (like getQueryString()), b/c I am not sure if it is possible to have  something like ?xyz being matched in a route.

Comment: Would the correct mod_rewrite be: `RewriteRule ^profile.php?id=(\d+)$ /profile/$1 [R=301]` ?

Comment: I just want to verify this is the best strategy, since I'm not an expert in Apache htaccess shenanigans

Comment: Me neither. You can test rewrites here: http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/. Though I would prefer to handle that with SF. Because routes are nowadays part of the model/logic.

Comment: @raffael1984 post params have nothing to do with routes. He should check the params in his controller, e.g `$request->query->getInt('id')`. This always returns an integer.

Comment: neither me nor martin is talking about POST-parameters

Comment: @raffael1984 and neither am I. Assuming `$request` is an instance of `Request`, my previous comment returns a GET-parameter. It would be `$request->request->getInt('id')` for POST-parameters. I just wanted to say that ?xyz cannot be matched by route and this is by design (Fabien himself mentioned it somewhere).

Comment: I know ... that's why I mention that it is necessary to use the Request instance